# Is it possible to fill a (tkinter based) GUI form and run it automatically from an external python/batch script?

Tags: python, bash, shell, tkinter

I have a python GUI based on tkinter with some entry widgets and buttons (say, program A). I want to populate this GUI (not manually) but using an external script (say program B). This script, B, could be in any language but preferably python or a batch file. Is there any mechanism I can expose the IDs of the GUI in program A to be used in program B.

[Program A is very much like Visual basic's ActiveX control consumed/used by program B.]
This could help in efficient testing of program A, for example.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This sounds complicated. In order for Python to interact with (theoretically) any language, you would have to create a pipe and send data that way. Program A would open the pipe, wait for certain data to be sent from Program B when Program B is launched, and then would use that data to create the widgets in the window. Of course, this means that _technically_ Program A is still creating its own widgets; but it's getting instructions for _how_ to do so from Program B. An alternative would be just to import and call Program B from Program A (assuming they're both written in Python).

Comment: You can read files into variables using read command in shell.  You can search files for regular expressions using grep, or pythons regular expressions.  You can search your source code for keywords and use the same keywords in your new program.